# Loop over document properties

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In my markdown header I have added a custom line:

```
---
layout: docs
title:  "My title"
date:   2015-09-18 22:40:58
permalink: /some/url/
custom: valueA valueB                 <---
---
```

And I managed to write the following template which processes these values:

```
{% capture custo %}{{page.custom}}{% endcapture %}
{% assign cust = custo|split:&nbsp; %}
{% for cus in cust%}
<code>{{ cus }}</code>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this seems much too complex to me. I have tried

- moving the assignment directly into `for`, which compiles but just outputs everything as one value, not as separate ones

  ```
  {% for cus in custo|split:&nbsp; %}
  ```
- getting rid of `capture`, but I get `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass` doing

  ```
  {% assign cust = page.custom|split:&nbsp; %}
  ```

Can my template be simplified or does it need to be that way? Or is it even the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing more research on this, I found out that the header is not only a header but actually YML. Therefore I can do

```
---
layout: docs
title:  "My title"
date:   2015-09-18 22:40:58
permalink: /some/url/
custom:
 1: valueA 
 2: valueB
---
```

and then use an ordinary loop

```
{% for cus in page.custom %}
<code>{{ cus[1] }}</code>
{% endfor %}
```